# Yii2 how to improve JWT caching?

Tags: php, caching, yii2, jwt

Trying to authenticate against a third party, I want to cache my returned JWT as long and robust as possible. (the expiration might change for example)

I wanted to use the `getOrSet` function of `Yii::$app->cache` in a more elaborate manner, but it is not possible to set the `duration` dynamically depending on the `token expiry` when handling everything within the `callable` part.

Am I missing anything in the Yii2 cache function here? Or is there a better library to cache my tokens that also supports passing a callable that retrieves the token?

My current code sample:

```
function getAccesToken($url)
{
    $cacheKey = 'login-token-' . $url;
    $token = Yii::$app->cache->get($cacheKey);
    // check if token is still valid (!== null) 
    // and is not expired using the loadToken function of bizley/jwt 
    // which returns null if token can not be validated
    // if valid a Lcobucci\JWT\Token is returned
    if ($token !== false && (new bizley\jwt\Jwt())->loadToken($token, true, false) !== null) {
        return $token;
    }
    $token = getTheJwtFromHttpEndpoint();
    // check if returned token is valid
    // returns a Lcobucci\JWT\Token if valid, null otherwise
    $token = (new bizley\jwt\Jwt())->loadToken($response, true, false); 
    if ($token === null) { 
        throw new \Exception('Invalid token received');
    }
    
    Yii::$app->cache->set(
        $cacheKey,
        $token->toString(),
        // set the cache duration oriented by the expiration claim and a one minute leeway
        $token->claims()->get('exp')->getTimestamp() - (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp() - 60
    );
    return $token->toString();
}
```

Comment: See [Cache Expiration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data#cache-expiration) and [Cache Dependencies](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data#cache-dependencies) to know more.You can use the 4th parameter `$dependency` of the [getOrSet()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-cache#getOrSet()-detail) method.According to the docs, If the dependency changes, the corresponding value in the cache will be invalidated when it is fetched via `get()`. This parameter is ignored if `$serializer` is `false`.

Comment: You are trying to use `getOrSet()` in wrong way. That method is just simplification of calling both `get()` and `set()` at same time for most basic cases. You are already calling `get()` at start of your method and anything after the first `if()` is only run when there is no valid token in cache. All you need to do is to use [`set()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-caching-cache#set()-detail) to store access token value instead of `getOrSet()` and then return the access token.

Comment: All that @MichalHynčica said is correct. I'm not sure though why do you need to store JWT in cache, it's against its purpose.

Comment: @Bizley because I have a web app with a configured technical user that needs an extra login request to a third-party API. I want to cache that third-party JWT to significantly reduce those login requests.